# Why i cant activate venv in bash shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash

When trying to activate a virtual environment in bash shell by using:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

bash shell output some errors:

```
dinir@DESKTOP-7IV447U:/mnt/c/online_store/djsite$ source venv/Scripts/activate
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: venv/Scripts/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'bash: venv/Scripts/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

Comment: your file is in CRLF, not LF